# Flutter: Disabling Multi-Touch/Drag with Gesture Detector

Tags: flutter, dart

Im currently building a Slider widget which multiple handle and am currently implementing the Gesture Detector. I am having an issue where if you touch/drag the screen with a second finger it will be recognised by the detector and call the onDragUpdate function, which is what I am trying to disable - whilst one finger is dragging the handle around, the gesture detector shouldn't call updates for a second finger but should still allow the first finger to call the updates.

For example, if you're sliding the handle around with finger 1 (fine) and then add a second finger, finger 2, the gesture detector should only recognise finger 1 even though both fingers are on screen.

I understand there is a function in the Listener class which allows you to specify a device (using details.device) but is there a way to achieve this using the Gesture Detector class?

Currently looking into different implementers for the Gesture Detector, including looking at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56037327/12147590 but i'm still struggling. If anyone could point me in the right direction or explain the answer further in simple terms for me that would be great, cheers :)

Comment: Are you sure, you actually need implementing your own slider? The on that is in the box is pretty customizable

Comment: Here it is, was released in Flutter 1.7: https://medium.com/flutter/material-range-slider-in-flutter-a285c6e3447d (and reference link just in case: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html)

Comment: I see you edited question. Just set an empty but non-null handlers for all multi-touch gestures

Comment: The app itself is based off custom widgets and this particular slider allows the use of more than 2 handles on the same slider (which the material apps don't implement)

Comment: More than 2 handlers? 0_o I've done many strange concepts, but that seems ridiculous))

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding what you mean, sorry

Comment: I've updated my answer, try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I was working on another separate problem I happened to have also solved this problem by using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58299959/12147590)

Answer (score 3):

According to the class [reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html):

> Attempts to recognize gestures that correspond to its non-null
>   callbacks.

So if you write it like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onDragUpdate: (updateDetails) {
    // Single finger drag, update your handlers
  },
  onPanDown: (_){}, 
  onPanStart: (_){}, 
  onPanUpdate: (_){}, 
  onPanEnd: (_){}, 
  onPanCancel: (){},
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    child: Text('TURN LIGHTS ON'),
  ),
)
```

It won't react on multi-touch, so you don't have to disable anything

UPD: according to question edit, you should set empty but non-null callbacks for all multi-touch events, so two fingers drag will be handled by empty callback, but single finger not

Comment: Using both the Pan and Scale callbacks gave an error as "scale is a superset of pan". Tried just using the scale callbacks but that hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either :/ There really needs to be a way to specify a pointer (just like you can do in the listener class)

Comment: I also just realised - this solution solve the full problem as I would still want the first finger to update the widget (even if the second finger is on screen).